# How do I perform output encoding on text boxes having fixed size?

Tags: xss, javascript, java

I have a fixed size text box which expects '<' and '>' symbols as input. It is a requirement for that text box to expect '<' and '>' in its input so I can't perform input validation for that text box.

I was trying to enforce output encoding mechanism but because of its (text box) fixed size and extra characters from encoding mechanism, some of the characters are getting truncated from being display as output.

In this situation how can I perform validation for that text box to prevent XSS attacks without loss of data? Note: I can't increase size of the text box dynamically.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?

Comment: What has a limited size here? The text box where the user enters the data? That should be no problem, since you encode after you read the data from the text box. The database where the data is stored? Just encode it when you read it from the DB; before you output it to the page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you really can't dynamically change the text box - but I would strongly suggest that you re-examine that fact as it does seem to be the easiest and safest way to get what you want.

You can't encode the output. There is just no way to encode `<` as something else without it being more character.

That means that you would need to apply some filter that filters out XSS attacks. This is a rather difficult task, so I would suggest to use an existing library for this, such as [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) for PHP or the [OWASP HTML Sanitizer](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer_Project) for Java.

Do note that filtering is a weaker form of protection than output encoding, and it will obviously change or reject some user input, which may or may not be acceptable.